# Collapse and Sum Data along multiple groupings in R

Tags: r, sorting

I have the following data table in R, which I need to collapse for streamlined data processing. I can do this manually, but I am looking for the most efficient way possible. The data frame looks like this:

[image]

and so on. Each age group has 4 observations, 2 male and 2 female (1 of each type). And region consists of city1, city2, city3, etc. which are all ordered the same as the example above. After all age groups are exhausted, the next cityX begins.

I need to combine gender into the total, summing males and females (within type). I also need to combine all age groups to give a population total (sum all age groups). I need to keep type separate, and then later combine them as an additional column. I want the final rows output to be the region. I need the population totals for each year column. So the final output would be like this:

[image]

I know this could be done manually by splitting the data frame repeatedly, but what would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Have your data in text format and not as an image. Best to do is to tidy the data by pivoting it into long format, groupby, summarize then pivot it wider

Comment: look into pivot_longer with tidyverse